# How to fix: "An object reference is required for the non-static field"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got the error Message:

> CS0120 - An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'StageDBEntities.Aufgaben'

My Code:

```
public ActionResult AufgabenDetails(int id)
{
    var Aufgabe = StageDBEntities.Aufgaben.Find(id);

    return View(Aufgabe);

}
```

This Code is on my Main Controller. With this i try to create a Site per Task(Aufgabe) in my Database.  /AufgabenDetails/1 <-- one is the ID of my Task(Aufgabe)

Comment: whether StageDBEntities is a class ? and it is not a static class to use StageDBEntities.Aufgaben, you have to create object of StageDBEntities and need to access

Comment: Did you look at the related column on the right? There are at least 10 duplicates of this error. Why you don't search before asking?

Answer (score 0):

You should creat an instance of StageDBEntities before trying to use it. Try

```js
public ActionResult AufgabenDetails(int id)
{
    var Aufgabe = new StageDBEntities().Aufgaben.Find(id);

    return View(Aufgabe);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If StageDBEntities is your Entity Framework class, you need to instantiate a new db instance as a variable

```
public ActionResult AufgabenDetails(int id)
{

    StageDBEntities db = new StageDBEntitites();
    var Aufgabe = db.Aufgaben.Find(id)

    return View(Aufgabe);

}
```